# Python automation: class and subclass 'AttributeError'

Tags: python, class, subclass, attributeerror

I am automating an instrument using Python, but I am new to using Python for object oriented programming.  I want to create several classes: a super class for the instrument and several subclasses to control particular components of the instrument (controller, sensor, etc.)

```
class instrument(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def function1(self):
        print 'Do something'

class component1(instrument):
    def __init__(self):
        super(component1, self).__init__()
    def function2(self):
        print 'Do something to component 1'
```

But, when I try to call component1:

```
I = instrument()
comp = I.component1()
```

I get an AttributeError:

```
AttributeError: 'instrument' object has no attribute 'component1'
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to access the `component1` class through the `instrument` one. Simply do

```
I = instrument()
comp = component1()
```

What you were doing was accessing the `component1` attribute of your `instrument` instance (which does not exist) , and not instanciating a new `component1`.

Answer (score 0):

`component1` is a subtype of `instrument`, so to create a `component1` object, you just need to create it. You especially don’t need to have an `instrument` object around to create it:

```
comp = component1()
comp.function1()
comp.function2()
```

It does not need to know that there is actually a base type involved.

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
comp = component1()
```

component1 is not part of instrument class, but class derived from it (so it is 'special' instrument). 
Also, it is good idea to Capitalize class names => Instrument, Compoment

Comment: That worked! Thanks. Also, it now seems that the __init__ function is not necessary.  Do I only use __init__ when I want the class to do something each time it is called?

Comment: An init without anything (just `pass`) does literally nothing, so you can just remove it. Calling the super’s init is a good idea though if you don’t exactly know whether or not the base type’s init does anything or not.

Comment: you use __init__ when you want custom constructor, i.e. to initialize some properties of *object* that your are creating. This *object* is an *instance* of *class* where you define your __init__. But this beyond this question and you will be better of reading a good tutorial on object oriented programming in python. GL.